# How do I flip a cubic curve upside down?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a cubic curve with a ball moving along the length as a sin wave. However, I would also like to have the option of a cosine at the same location. How do I do this though? Rotate certainly doesn't work.

Here's the Cubic Curve I have which represents the sin:

```
CubicCurve sin = new CubicCurve();
sin.setStartX(0.0f);
sin.setStartY(200.0f);
sin.setControlX1(100.0f);
sin.setControlY1(0.0f);
sin.setControlX2(300.0f);
sin.setControlY2(400.0f);
sin.setEndX(400.0f);
sin.setEndY(200.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution is to just switch the Y1 and Y2 values like so:

```
CubicCurve cosine = new CubicCurve();
cosine.setStartX(0.0f);
cosine.setStartY(200.0f);
cosine.setControlX1(100.0f);
cosine.setControlY1(400.0f);
cosine.setControlX2(300.0f);
cosine.setControlY2(0.0f);
cosine.setEndX(400.0f);
cosine.setEndY(200.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cubic Curve:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CubicCurve.html)

> The CubiCurve class defines a cubic Bézier parametric curve segment in
>   (x,y) coordinate space. Drawing a curve that intersects both the
>   specified coordinates (startX, startY) and (endX, enfY), using the
>   specified points (controlX1, controlY1) and (controlX2, controlY2) as
>   Bézier control points.

So what you have to do is to flip the control points.